# File icon with a cross, what does it mean?

Tags: icons

A file icon shown below has a cross on the lower right corner, what does that mean?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't have read permission for that file.

Answer (score 3):

Simple self-answering test:

- **Create an empty file**

  ```
  touch ~/bar
  ```

  [image]
- **Remove the read permissions**

  ```
  chmod -r ~/bar
  ```

  [image]

Comment: Neat icons. What are they called?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Numix Circle is the icon theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide others read access to that file so that it wont display.

**sudo chmod o+r <your_filename>**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1282491)